# differential equation with linear coeffcients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation $(a_1 x+b_1 y+c_1)dx+(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)dy=0 $ with following conditions

$$ (|c_1|+|c_2|\neq 0),  \quad\quad\quad   (a_2\neq b1) ,\quad\quad\quad (a_1b_2-a_2b_1=0),\quad\quad\quad (b_2\neq 0, a_1\neq 0, a_1-a_2\neq b_1-b_2) $$

The question states that describe the affect of each of these conditions on the equation and find a way to solve it.

My attempt:

using the third condition we have $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = \frac{b_2}{b_1} = \lambda$ so we have $a_2 = \lambda a_1 , b_2 = \lambda b_1$

substituting in equation we have

$$(a_1x + b_1y + c_1)dx + (\lambda a_1 x + \lambda b_2 y +c_2)dy = 0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{a_1 x + b_1 y +c_1}{\lambda a_1 + \lambda b_2 y + c_2}$$

substituting with $z = a_1 x + b_1 y$ we have

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = g(z)$$ where $g(z) = \frac{z+c_1}{\lambda z + c_2}$

differentiate $z = a_1 x + b_1 y$ with respect to $x$

$$ \frac{dz}{dx} = a_1 + b_1 \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now substitute $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{b_1(z+c_1)}{\lambda z + c_2} + a_1$$
Now it's a separable equation and we can find solutions to it by integrating each side.

In my attempt I only used third condition and the other conditions did not matter. Is my attempt right? and what is the meaning of the other conditions?